# AWS Elasticsearch TransportError(413, '')

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, transport

We are using the python elasticsearch API version "elasticsearch-6.8.0"
With AWS Elasticsearch version 6.7

It only happens sometimes, on some machines (even when we make the queries within seconds of each other from different machines, one will succeed and the other will throw the error).  Thus this is difficult to reproduce.  We are using a paginated search like this:

```
def scrolled_search_query(self, index, query, size=es_config.ES_SIZE,
                              scroll=es_config.ES_SCROLL,
                              request_timeout=es_config.ES_TIMEOUT,
                              docs_only=False):
        data = self.es_conn.search(index=index, size=size, scroll=scroll, body=query,
                                   request_timeout=request_timeout)

        while len(data['hits']['hits']) > 0:
            for hit in data['hits']['hits']:
                if docs_only:
                    yield hit['_source']
                else:
                    yield hit

            data = self.es_conn.scroll(scroll_id=data['_scroll_id'], scroll=scroll,
                                       request_timeout=request_timeout)
```

The error message is utterly useless, just basically saying that there's a 413. like this:

**`TransportError: TransportError(413, '')`**

From looking around at forums, it seems the problem is because ES is attempting to return a large payload.  However, since we're using scroll pagination, I don't know why this would be an issue because each payload should be well below the 100MB limit.  Since the error message is so terrible, I can't really see what it's trying to do in the database.  It seems like the database is calculating the total data for the query and rejecting it without taking into account pagination. It's normal for us to request large payloads, and paginate them.

The full exception looks like this, what else do you need?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TransportError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a3fd964bf999> in <module>
     41                                  blah=blah,
     42                                  blah=blah,
---> 43                                  start_date=start_date)
     44 
     45         df = df.drop(['@blah', '@blah'], axis=1)
~/Documents/Repositories/blah/blah/downloader.py in get_data(self, data_type, blah, blah, device, blah, start_date, end_date)
    186             return self.gatorEs.get_blah(es_requests=self.es_requests, blah=blah, blah=blah, blah=blah,
--> 188                                            start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
    189 
    190         if data_type == 'blah':
~/Documents/Repositories/gator_access/gator_access/es_gator_api.py in get_blah(self, es_requests, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, start_date, end_date)
    180                                             logger=self.logger)
    181                     if not data: continue
--> 182                     es_data += data
    183 
    184         self.logger.info(" ".join(["Download took {t} seconds for p:'{p}' d:'{d}'",
~/Documents/Repositories/gator_core/gator_core/elasticsearch/es_requests.py in scrolled_search_query(self, index, query, size, scroll, request_timeout, docs_only)
    144 
    145             data = self.es_conn.scroll(scroll_id=data['_scroll_id'], scroll=scroll,
--> 146                                        request_timeout=request_timeout)
    147 
    148 
~/anaconda3/envs/prognostic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     82                 if p in kwargs:
     83                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
---> 84             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
     85 
     86         return _wrapped
~/anaconda3/envs/prognostic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py in scroll(self, scroll_id, body, params)
   1353         """
   1354         return self.transport.perform_request(
-> 1355             "GET", _make_path("_search", "scroll", scroll_id), params=params, body=body
   1356         )
   1357 
~/anaconda3/envs/prognostic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py in perform_request(self, method, url, headers, params, body)
    351                     headers=headers,
    352                     ignore=ignore,
--> 353                     timeout=timeout,
    354                 )
    355 
~/anaconda3/envs/prognostic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore, headers)
    139                 raw_data,
    140             )
--> 141             self._raise_error(response.status_code, raw_data)
    142 
    143         self.log_request_success(
~/anaconda3/envs/prognostic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py in _raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    160 
    161         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
--> 162             status_code, error_message, additional_info
    163         )
TransportError: TransportError(413, '')
```